# what will be best approach for service monitor in spring cloud

Tags: spring-cloud

I am now using spring cloud to build micro service application, and now I need to create service monitoring solution to dynamically check status for each micro-service. 
I am not seeing this supported in spring cloud, but I did see NetFlix is providing Srvo, does anyone ever used it or can anyone give some good suggestions on what will be best solution to monitor status for all the micro-services?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Spring Cloud Netflix adds servo metrics to the standard spring boot `/metrics` actuator endpoint.  See [Spring Boot Production Ready Metrics](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html) to see about a  `MetricRepository`.  Here is [some documentation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-docs/src/main/asciidoc/production-ready-features.adoc#metric-writers-exporters-and-aggregation) on using redis.  See [this project](https://github.com/scratches/aggregator/blob/master/generator/src/main/java/demo/GeneratorApplication.java#L61) for an example configuration.